# Understanding "being forced out of my comfort zone"

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

In this speech…

> I love meeting and getting to know new people. One of my favorite things in life is cooking, mostly for other people. I'm looking for someone who enjoys trying new food, from my kitchen and others'. Also love travel and adventure. **And being forced out of my comfort zone** from time to time. I've been to a few amazing places, but there's so much more I want to see and do. Love love movies, pretty much all genres, and I love going to the theater as much as staying in watching movies too. I'm a funny, energetic, sharp-witted woman who appreciates all the little things in life. I love learning and I'm always trying to expand my horizons. "The day you stop learning is the day you die." I like people who make me laugh because honestly, I love to laugh. Looking for a fun, intelligent, driven, open-minded, down-to-earth, silly, sarcastic person who doesn't take themselves too seriously. Life is short, eat dessert first, right?

1. What does the speeker mean by saying **being forced**  and **comfort zone** ?
2. Is **being forced** grammatically passive or active phrase? I mean to say is it refering to act with force or something else?

Comment: See also: https://books.google.com/books?id=vVBo4MmXS-4C&pg=PA396 (Passive Participial Phrases)

Answer (score 4):

**[to force](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/force_2)** (a verb):

> to make someone do something they do not want to do

This doesn't have to include a violent physical act, although one of the meanings of *force* as a noun is exactly this one and the [origins](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=force&searchmode=none) of both are linked to this meaning. It usually means an involuntary or unwilling action caused by an exterior source - it might be a person, or just circumstances.

> 1. The rain started and we were **forced** to go inside.
> 2. Mother always **forced** me to eat spinach, even though I hate it.
> 3. Facing serious financial problems, he was **forced** to start working again.

**[comfort zone](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/comfort-zone)**

> your comfort zone is the range of activities or situations that you feel happy and confident in

*Edit from comment: 'outside one's comfort zone' is idiomatic (and often preceded by a verb). One can step/move/go/stretch etc. [outside their comfort zone](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22outside%22+%22comfort+zone%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22outside%22%2B%22comfort+zone%22&tbm=bks&start=40).*

So:

> Being forced out of my comfort zone

Means that something has made me do something outside the range of activities or put myself in situations different than dose I'm used to and feel confident in.

(Definitions from LDOCE)

A **passive voice** construction would be made like this:

> New rules of this cooking competition forced me out of my comfort zone. (active)
>
> I was forced out of my comfort zone (by the new rules of this cooking competition). (passive)

However, *being forced out of my comfort zone* is not a complete sentence. *Forced out of my comfort zone* is a **participle phrase** and *being forced out of my comfort zone* fits the definition of a **[passive participle phrase](https://books.google.rs/books?id=vVBo4MmXS-4C&pg=PA396&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)** (from the reference provided in the comments).

Comment: It might be worth adding as a footnote that to be "_verbed_ outside of one's comfort zone" is somewhat idiomatic. I might be _nudged_ outside of my comfort zone, or I might _step_ outside of my comfort zone. For example: _Having grown up in a rural town, I was a bit scared to take a job in New York, but I figured it was time for me to step out of my comfort zone._

Comment: @J.R. I had to look up what inadvertently means :-). Thanks for the edit! I'll add the part about 'outside one's comfort zone' being idiomatic.

Comment: I added a link to Passive Participial Phrases in a book in my comment to the OP above. Please feel free to use the information in the page as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks , it is a great resource :-). I haven't realized I drifted too far from the OP's construction in my answer. But when I think about it carefully something bothers me. The sentence actually reads: I like **being forced out of my comfort zone**. Sicne 'like' is always transitive, this construction functions as its direct object. Can it still be a passive participle phrase or is it something more complicated?